# Copy part of string field (in table A) into a new field (table B) connected by a table C

Tags: mysql, select, position, substring

Let's say i've in a mysql db:

- table called "user" with "id_user" and "extrafield"
- table called "connection" with "id_user" and "id_content"
- table called "content" with "id_content" and "user_content"

Into "user_content" i've multiple fields inside like:

```
<br />::field1::fieldvalue::/field1::<br />::field2::fieldvalue::/field2::<br />
```

What's the best query to copy "field2" value from "content" inside "extrafield" in "user" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @user = 1;

UPDATE content
SET content.user_content = replace(content.user_content, 'field2', 
         (SELECT extrafield FROM user WHERE id_user = @user))
WHERE content.id_content 1;
```

This query will do the replace for you. You have to join the tables appropriately though.

Comment: this can't work. I've to use substring to get the value from content.

Comment: Are you copying from content to user then? I thought it was the other way around.

Comment: And are the <br/> tags part of the field value?

Comment: You will have to look at a regular expression solution then. maybe using regexp() function.

Comment: Yes, <br />::field1::fieldvalue::/field1::<br />::field2::fieldvalue::/field2::<br /> is an example  of the user_content's field